Creating Lua filters; tikz externalize trouble
This is a draft of the Lua filter that I plan to use with Pandoc. The goal of this filter is to locate images created synthetically with TikZ (no images imported with `\usegraphicÚ), create a standalone file containing the tikz image and convert it to svg format.
The error message I see is the following:
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "figures/output-figure0" "\def\tikzexterna
lrealjob{output}\input{output}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'figure
s/output-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that y
ou have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. S
ometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the comma
nd simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'figures/output-figure0.log'. 
If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

and the Lua code is
local file = "C:/Logs/test.tex"

function file_exists(name)
    local f = io.open(name, "r")
    if f ~= nil then
        io.close(f)
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end

function get_line(filename, line_number)
    local i = 0
    for line in io.lines(filename) do
        i = i + 1
        if i == line_number then
            return line
        end
    end
    return nil -- line not found
end

function lines_from(file)
    if not file_exists(file) then
        return {}
    end
    local lines = {}
    for line in io.lines(file) do
        lines[#lines + 1] = line
    end
    return lines
end

local lines = lines_from(file)

io.output("C:/Logs/output.tex")

io.write("\\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}", "\n")
io.write("\\usepackage{tikz}", "\n")
io.write("\\usepackage{pgfplots}", "\n")
io.write("\\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}", "\n")
io.write("\\usepackage{siunitx}", "\n")
io.write("\\usetikzlibrary{external}", "\n")
io.write("\\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/]", "\n")
io.write("\\begin{document}", "\n")

for k, v in pairs(lines) do
    if string.find(v, "\\begin{tikzpicture}") then
        io.write("\\begin{tikzpicture}\n", "\n")
        local i = k + 1
        while not string.find(lines[i], "\\end{tikzpicture}") do
            io.write(lines[i], "\n")
            i = i + 1
        end
    end
end
io.write("\\end{tikzpicture}\n", "\n")
io.write("\\end{document}\n", "\n")
io.close()
os.execute("cd C:/Logs & pdflatex -shell-escape output.tex")

Lua code ran with NppExec with the terminal commands
SET interpreter = C:\Lua\lua54.exe
SET exec = "$(interpreter)" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
NPP_SAVE
$(exec)
if $(EXITCODE) != 0 goto exit
NPP_CONSOLE 1
NPP_RUN cmd /C "cmd /C $(exec) && pause"
:exit

Tex file generated via Lua script:
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[
            colorbar,
            colorbar style={
                title=$V$,
                ylabel=\unit{\kilo\cal} \unit{\mol^{-1}},
                ytick={0,50,100,150,200,250},
                xshift=1cm
            },
            xtick={1,2,3,4},xmin=1,xmax=4.5,
            ytick={1,2,3,4},ymin=1,ymax=4.5,
            ztick={0,50,100,150,200,250},zmin=0,zmax=250,
            xlabel={$r_{\mathrm{AB}}\hspace{3px}\left(\unit{\angstrom}\right)$},
            ylabel={$r_{\mathrm{BC}}\hspace{3px}\left(\unit{\angstrom}\right)$},
            zlabel={$V \hspace{3px} \left(\unit{\kilo\cal} \hspace{3px} \unit{\mol^{-1}}\right)$},
            % tick align=outside,
            zticklabel style={yshift=5pt},
            xticklabel style={xshift=5pt},
            x label style={yshift=0.25cm},
            y label style={yshift=0.5cm},
        ]
            \addplot3 [surf,shader=flat,draw=black,domain=1:4.5,y domain=1:4.5] {(128*(1-exp(-(x-1.3)))^2)+(128*(1-exp(-(y-1.3)))^2)};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Is the file written correctly? Does it compile if you compile it directly? Note that the external library is basically unmaintained, as I understand it, and the developers recommend alternatives (memoize or robust-externalize).

Yes, it compile fine without tikz externalize

But does it compile with externalize, if you run it directly rather than via Lua?

No it doesn't compile

What's the content of the file which gives the error? As you probably know, not all pictures can be externalised, so any document subject to this filter is likely to need some overrides to prevent attempts to externalise particular pictures.

I added the .tex file generated via Lua script into my question

At this point, I'd just block externalisation for the problematic picture. At least, that's what I used to do. These days, I'm transitioning to one of the newer options. These are less stable but memoize, at least, is more reliable. It can externalise pictures which stump external and it can abort externalisation automatically in many problem cases. That said, you still need some fine-tuning in the document, depending on exactly what you're doing. No solution I'm aware of can cope out-of-the-box with all cases.

[I don't mean robust-externalize isn't more reliable. I just haven't tried it.]

Why do you want to externalise the pictures at all? You're essentially creating documents which contain only the pictures, so why not compile them without externalising? What's the advantage of externalising in this scenario?

This script are intented to work with pandoc to import  synthetically-created tikz images (no images imported with \usegraphic please) to .docx document

But externalising isn't doing anything because you're effectively externalising by hand anyway. If you just compile the standalone file with pdflatex without shell escape, you just have a more efficient process. There's no advantage to externalising a file which consists entirely of a single picture. Just compile the file.

The sole purpose of externalisation is to create the images independently of the document. You might do this for various reasons: to speed compilation (typically) or because you want to manipulate the images (in your case).
But your Lua code separates the code for each image into its own file. When Lua invokes pdflatex it compiles a document which contains nothing but the code for a single image. So the image is already separate and externalising it simply complicates processing by initiating a second compilation run.
The solution is to have Lua invoke pdflatex in the normal way (probably without --shell-escape unless needed for something else) and not to add the code for externalisation into the written .tex file. Then compilation will succeed provided only that the code for the image can be compiled successfully with pdflatex and you will have your 'externalised' image as PDF. You can then post-process that image however you want instead or (or in addition to) any use made of it in the document.
Note that the following is untested as it certainly would not work on my machine, which does not have Windows.
local file = "C:/Logs/test.tex"

function file_exists(name)
    local f = io.open(name, "r")
    if f ~= nil then
        io.close(f)
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end

function get_line(filename, line_number)
    local i = 0
    for line in io.lines(filename) do
        i = i + 1
        if i == line_number then
            return line
        end
    end
    return nil -- line not found
end

function lines_from(file)
    if not file_exists(file) then
        return {}
    end
    local lines = {}
    for line in io.lines(file) do
        lines[#lines + 1] = line
    end
    return lines
end

local lines = lines_from(file)

io.output("C:/Logs/output.tex")

io.write("\\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}", "\n")
io.write("\\usepackage{tikz}", "\n")
io.write("\\usepackage{pgfplots}", "\n")
io.write("\\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}", "\n")
io.write("\\usepackage{siunitx}", "\n")
io.write("\\begin{document}", "\n")

for k, v in pairs(lines) do
    if string.find(v, "\\begin{tikzpicture}") then
        io.write("\\begin{tikzpicture}\n", "\n")
        local i = k + 1
        while not string.find(lines[i], "\\end{tikzpicture}") do
            io.write(lines[i], "\n")
            i = i + 1
        end
    end
end
io.write("\\end{tikzpicture}\n", "\n")
io.write("\\end{document}\n", "\n")
io.close()
os.execute("cd C:/Logs & pdflatex output.tex")

This produces exactly the same result as you would achieve with successful externalisation except that

no hash is created;
only one set of auxiliary files is written (.log, .aux etc.);
only one compilation process is used per picture;
only one PDF image is produced per picture (but you could easily copy it to <filename>-figure0.pdf if you need two);
all complications of externalisation are avoided.

Of course, this won't work for arbitrary tikzpicture environments because these may depend on additional configuration outside that environment, but that is true regardless of whether externalisation is used or not.
Likewise, the filter obviously isn't cross-platform but, again, that's independent of the externalisation issue.
